# Cross-Origin Request Blocked At time of sending post request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have 2 servers and 2 domains I want to send a post request from one domain to another but my browser shows an error

> access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com' from origin 'https://www.example2.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

the javascript code i am using To  send Post Data is

```
<script>
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "key": "value sent"
});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});
xhr.open("POST", "https://example.com");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.send(data);
</script>
```

So My question is how I can resolve this problem and send a Post request to another domain and which method to use to send post request

Comment: Did you search for CORS like the error tells you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: the server allows cors? if not you have to enable it

Comment: @epascarello yes I already read the document but couldn't understand I have to add allow headers on my site or the site I am trying to access???

Comment: The backend has to set CORS. There is nothing you can do from the clientside. They need to give you permission to use the content, the browser requires that the permission is there. If not, you can not access it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable CORS on your server. In case of NodJs you can do something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // request from other domain will work here
});
```

in browser use

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}
```

Comment: I am requesting that rest api completely from my browser using js and not using any back-end.  ..

Comment: Rember that server you are requesting data need to have CORS enabled, its why i added server part code. If your server not accept CORS you will not get data you want.

Comment: If you can have access to your server code you can add few lines to enable cors if not it will be not possible to use ajax ion such server.

Comment: I have cors enabled. get request succeeds but post request fails. thanks